# VBA code for iterations

Tags: vba, iterator

I have a list of about 2-350 unique units, or apartments.

I need to group them based on four criteria - number of bathrooms, bedrooms, floor area, and wall area. Grouped units must have the same number of bed and bathrooms and be within 10% (so +/- 10%) of the **unit** that's being chosen to represent that group.

This means that depending on what unit I choose, there will be different possibilities for number of groups and what they are.

I need to reduce the amount of groups.

I don't need actual code so much as just the logical, mathematical approach to this.

Right now, I'm just performing 4 sorts and manually selecting them.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on the question, I'd have my data arranged as follows

`Apt Num    Bath    Bed Floor   Wall`

like

```
Apt Num Bath    Bed Floor   Wall
Appt 1  1   2   100 500
Appt 2  1   3   200 600
Appt 3  1   4   300 700
Appt 4  1   2   100 500
Appt 5  2   3   200 600
Appt 6  2   4   300 700
Appt 7  2   2   100 500
Appt 8  1   3   200 600
Appt 9  1   4   300 700
Appt 10 2   2   100 500
```

in Columns A to E

In Columns G to J I would have what constitutes a group, as follows

```
Bath    Bed Floor   Wall
2         3 200     600
```

Then, where ever, next to this, I have used L2 to L11, I have the following ARRAY formula copied down

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$11,SMALL(IF((($B$2:$B$11=$G$2)*($C$2:$C$11=$H$2)*($D$2:$D$11=$I$2)*($E$2:$E$11=$J$2)),ROW($B$2:$B$11)),ROWS($M$2:$M2)),1),"----")
```

Which gives the following output 
                ----
[image]